# How should i proceed with game development?

Tags: android, game-engine

I have developed a few android applications. Now, I was thinking about developing some games for android. I have a few doubts, I need to be clear about. I have never created any game before. I know Java at intermediate level.

1. Should I consider using a game engine to develop my games?
2. What are benefits of using a game engine? Does it allow me to build specific type of games or any kind that I like? How long will it take to learn how to use a specific game engine?
3. What does game engine do for me, like does it provide me with built in collision detection? Exactly how it would be useful?
4. I have also heard that we can also develop games using HTML5 and the games would be cross platform. Why or why not should O consider developing games in HTML5?

Some questions might not make any sense because I have just started.

Comment: Not to be rude but, if you haven't searched for any of this to have a more specific question then, no, no you probably shouldn't start game development.

Comment: From no idea about game engines to a complete home made game in 30 days... I wish you luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider posting that on the [game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Anyway, it really depends of the game you want to code. For 2-Dimensional games, i don't really see the use of a game engine. Tilemapping, 2D physics / collision, AI implementation and things are quite easy (but very instructive) to implement.
For 3D games it's another thing. Collisions are a pain to implement yourself, just as a decent physic engine (in the case of a racing game for instance). There you should consider using a prebuilt engine.

Comment: Thanx , mate. It cleared my doubt about using game engines.

Comment: Np, feel free to upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing better than using a library that has already solved your problem and is stable and ready to use. Never re-invent the wheel. You need collision detection? Make a list of other things you need. Find a set of library that covers your problems and you are ready to take off.